# Trying to convert a column in a CSV file from UTC time to US/Pacific time

Tags: python, pandas, time, timezone

So I have the task to read a CSV file and convert the column of times of emails being sent to a new time zone (From UTC to pacific) I feel like I have tried everything, my current code where the error is
`df_emails = df_emails.EmailSentDateTimeUtc.dt.tz_localize('US/Eastern', ambiguous='infer')`
I have tried with ambiguous set to true as well as raise, the "EmailSentDateTimeUtc" column has been converted to a datetime64[ns]
im trying to localize to eastern and then convert to pacific.

the error being thrown from that code is
`AmbiguousTimeError: 2018-11-04 01:58:16.743000`

slowly losing my mind here, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read date/time data that is in UTC, you should specify that upon import / when converting from string to datetime datatype. Then the conversion to another time zone won't cause any errors.

**EX:**

```
import pandas as pd

df_emails = pd.DataFrame({"EmailSentDateTimeUtc": ["2018-11-04 01:58:16.743000"]})

# to datetime, and specifiy that input is UTC
df_emails.EmailSentDateTimeUtc = pd.to_datetime(df_emails.EmailSentDateTimeUtc, utc=True)

# now you can convert easily like
df_emails.EmailSentDateTimeUtc = df_emails.EmailSentDateTimeUtc.dt.tz_convert('US/Eastern')

# df_emails
#               EmailSentDateTimeUtc
# 0 2018-11-03 21:58:16.743000-04:00
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It runs perfectly now, I am so extremely grateful for your response!